# Reading PDF in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

In windows phone I have installed adobe reader its very nice but I am not able to jump to particular page I need to start from the starting . Its very difficult if we are reading book please any one have any solution for that.

Comment: Are you looking to create your own application or are you looking for an alternative application to the Adobe Reader app?

Comment: My own apps still long way to go. I want an alternate to adobe reader to read pdf files in which I can jump to particular page number.

Comment: There is not a good way to do this out of the box. Are you willing to look at using a third party app to accomplish this? Unfortunately I see it as your only option right now. Downside is that you cannot install an app to be used as the "default" PDF reader other than the one adobe provides. I would encourage you to reach out to the Adobe folks and ask for the feature you want to be included in the next release of the app.

Comment: @Megharaj, would you mind marking my answer (posted below) as the answer? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest adobe reader version released for the windows phone is working fine. We can go to particular pages also many advancement. SO the problem no more exist.

Answer (score 2):

(reposting my comment as an answer for your approval so this question can get marked as answered):

There is not a good way to do this out of the box. Are you willing to look at using a third party app to accomplish this? Unfortunately I see it as your only option right now. Downside is that you cannot install an app to be used as the "default" PDF reader other than the one adobe provides. I would encourage you to reach out to the Adobe folks and ask for the feature you want to be included in the next release of the app.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try and ebook reader for windows phone 7:
http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2011/03/20/samsung-ebook-reader-for-windows-phone-7-hands-on-video-review/

If it isnt what youre looking for just google for ebook reader,

cheers :)